# Add a link to Reading List from Terminal

Tags: terminal, safari, applescript, reading-list

Is it possible to add the links to the Reading List from terminal or Alfred without opening Safari?

Maybe some AppleScript snippet would do?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems that somebody thought about that already. Here is an Alfred workflow that does exactly that:

https://www.alfredforum.com/topic/4524-safari-reading-list/